# How is this sentence/saying structured?

Tags: grammar, translation, syntax

I have problems understanding the correct grammatical structure of this saying:

金は取れる時に取れるところから取れるだけ取っておくものだ

[image]

I kind of understand what it is saying. I think its something like "At a time where there is money to be taken, you should take it all". But i struggle with the parts like

- what meaning has kara in 取れるところ**から**
- what does this mean 取れるだけ取って
- what means ~おく in とって**おく**もの. 
  Is it like the structure "verb + te + oku" or is it okumono -> a
  thing that was placed?

This saying appears multiple times in the manga and it starts to bug me.
If somebody is interested to explain this I would be very happy about it ;]

Greetings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「金{かね}は取{と}れる時に取れるところから取れるだけ取っておくものだ。」

I shall insert commas so that the sentence might look somewhat more manageable to some.

> 「金は、取れる時に、取れるところから、取れるだけ、取っておくものだ。」

The core of this sentence is:

> 「金は取っておくものだ。」　("One should take/earn money.")

The original sentence adds three qualifiers to the core as below:

> 「金は (when) (from where/who) (how much) 取っておくものだ。」

「取れる時に」 = whenever one can take it

「取れるところ**から**」 = **from** wherever/whoever one can take it

「取れるだけ」 = as much as one can take

> おく in とっておくもの. Is it like the structure "verb + te + oku" or is it okumono -> a thing that was placed?

The former.  Latter makes no sense for the context.

> "Money is something that you should take whenever possible, wherever possible and as much as possible."